# Changes in "Simple Markup" mode using Office JS API

Tags: office-js

Using Office JS we are trying to choose also the mode of “Track Changes” as simple markup
Launch Word 2016
Go to REVIEW tab
Under TRACKING you will see a drop down with Simple markup, All markup, no markup, Original

We want to select by default “Simple Markup” whenever our Office JS task pane addin is getting loaded.

During our tests it seems that this cannot be set using Open xml. 
We are not sure that this mode is takes into account user´s preferences, not the document settings.
How can we activate “Simple Markup” using Office JS API or Open xml?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately is not possible to modify the tracking mode with Office.js, and effectively OOXML is not an alternative for it.

Will be great if you can vote for this feature (or create a new one) in our Uservoice channel.

thanks
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: Just found out this is a feature request for a while already. What way can OfficeJS users make changes if OOXML is not an alternative?